# What's the meaning of "Maçarico" in European Portuguese?

Tags: significado, português-europeu

The word "Maçarico" refers to a tool that sets fire, used for many purposes. I did some research and discovered that it also refers to a specific type of bird.

However, when I was listening to the music "Numa Numa" by the band "Onda Choc" (portuguese version of the famous song [dragostea din tei](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Z4xc3dXDE5I)), I noticed that in the song the word "Maçarico" is used in another way:

> Alô! Olá jóia! Sou eu de novo! O Picasso!  Mas não me faças num
>   fanico. **Eu não sou um maçarico!**
>
> Eu liguei, numa boa, hei! Numa boa, hei! Numa numa boa, hei! Eu cá
>   estou, sem drama aguardarei. O amor vem mas também vai.

See the video [here](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5z0L9ZUlTnE)(BTW, very funny video)

What's the meaning of the word "Maçarico" in this context?

Comment: "Tem carta de condução há 2 meses ainda é maçarico."

Answer (score 9, accepted):

*A [maçarico](http://www.priberam.pt/dlpo/ma%C3%A7arico)* in that context means *a [rookie](http://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/american_english/rookie?q=rookie)*, someone who is new to an activity and has very little experience.

The other meaning, the fire-spitting tool, is a blowtorch.